# How to insert records with DataSnap

Tags: delphi, insert, datasnap

In many tutorials i read how to select data from a database in a datasnap client, p.e. to complete a dbgrid.
But i need now to know how to insert or update a row, p.e  "new client". Can everybody recommends me a book or tutorial?

I have an sqlconnection on a clientdatamodule on the clientside apart from clientclassesunit. I was prooving wuth an SQLQuery with an insert SQL Statement but it doen't function.

On the other han i have on the server side:

```
procedure TServerMethods1.nuevocheque(idcliente,numero,cuenta,idbanco : integer; fr,fc, titular:string ;importe:Double;cobrado:Boolean);
var
ucheque:integer;
begin
  with qicheque do
    begin
      Open;
      ParamByName('idcliente').AsInteger:=idcliente;
      ParamByName('numero').AsInteger:=numero;
      ParamByName('fr').AsDate:=StrToDate(fr);
      ParamByName('fc').AsDate:=StrToDate(fc);
      ParamByName('importe').AsFloat:=importe;
      ParamByName('titular').AsString:=titular;
      ParamByName('cobrado').AsBoolean:=cobrado;
      ParamByName('cuenta').AsInteger:=cuenta;

      ExecSQL();

    end;
end;
```

With this method i try to insert, the statement is into SQL property of the component.

On the client side, i have  a TSQLServerMethod wich calls "nuevocheque":

```
procedure TForm4.BGuardarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
idcliente,numero,cuenta,idbanco:integer;
titular:string;
cobrado:Boolean;
fr,fc:string;
importe:Double;
begin
  ClientModule1.nuevocheque.Create(nil);
  with ClientModule1.nuevocheque do
  begin

    idcliente:=1;
    numero:=StrToInt(ENumero.Text);
    cuenta:=StrToInt(Ecuenta.Text);
    idbanco:=1;
    titular:=ENombre.Text;
    cobrado:=False;
    importe:=StrToFloat(EMonto.Text);
    fr:=EFechaEmision.Text;
    fc:=EFechacobro.Text;


  end;

end;
```

But it doesn´t function.
Thank for your help

Comment: For sure remove the `Open` call from your code. If your `qicheque` contains a prepared SQL statement, just fill the params and call `ExecSQL`.

Comment: Which server back-end are you using, MS Sql Server, MySql, etc?

Comment: MySQL, i have workbench

Answer (score 1):

Well, i achieve inserting data into mysql database i had desgined.

This is te code in delphi into a button:

```
procedure TForm4.BGuardarClick(Sender: TObject);
var

idcliente,numero,cuenta,idbanco:integer;
titular:string;
cobrado:Boolean;
fr,fc:string;
importe:Double;
a:TServerMethods1Client;
interes:Double;
begin
  a:=TServerMethods1Client.Create(ClientModule1.SQLConnection1.DBXConnection);


  begin

    idcliente:=Unit3.id;
    numero:=StrToInt(ENumero.Text);
    cuenta:=StrToInt(Ecuenta.Text);
    idbanco:=lcbbanco.KeyValue;
    titular:=ENombre.Text;
    cobrado:=False;
    if (EP.Text<>'') then
       begin
         importe:=StrToFloat(EHC.Text);
       end
       else
        begin
          importe:=StrToFloat(EMonto.Text);
        end;

    fr:=EFechaEmision.Text;
    fc:=EFechacobro.Text;


  end;
   a.nuevocheque(idcliente,numero,cuenta, idbanco,fr,fc,titular,importe,cobrado);
end;
```

I've called to method create() with the SQL component such as M Diwo said me.

Im too hapy. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you use as database connection, for my own convenience I have slightly modified for dbGO (parameters passed by variant).
Also I have made a function from the server method, like this the client can be notified that there has been a problem (with the query, connection,...). Here is the server method:

```
//server
function TServerMethods1.NuevoCheque(idcliente, numero, cuenta,
  idbanco: integer; fr, fc, titular: string; importe: Double;
  cobrado: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  try
    with qicheque, Parameters do
      begin
        Close;
        ParamByName('idcliente').Value:=idcliente;
        ParamByName('numero').Value:=numero;
        ParamByName('fr').Value:=StrToDate(fr);
        ParamByName('fc').Value:=StrToDate(fc);
        ParamByName('importe').Value:=importe;
        ParamByName('titular').Value:=titular;
        ParamByName('cobrado').Value:=cobrado;
        ParamByName('cuenta').Value:=cuenta;
        ExecSQL();
      end;
      Result := true;
  except
    Result := false;
    //raise; <-- uncomment if you want to handle this properly in your code
  end;
end;
```

For the client I suppose you generated a proxy unit that generally creates an object called ServerMethods1 ? 
You must pass the client dbx connection to this - I say this because I saw you put nil in your code.

```
// client
procedure TfrmClient.BGuardaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sm : TServerMethods1Client; // <-- generated by proxy generator
  idcliente,numero,cuenta,idbanco : integer;
  fr,fc, titular : string ;
  importe : Double;
  cobrado : Boolean;
begin
  sm := TServerMethods1Client.Create(SQL.DBXConnection);
  if sm.nuevocheque(idcliente,numero,cuenta,idbanco, fr,fc, titular, importe, cobrado) then
    // ok
  else
    // error
  sm.Free;
end;
```

hth

Comment: You are losing type safety when assigning param values through the `Value` property.

Comment: `code` sm := TServerMethods1Client.Create(SQL.DBXConnection); `code`   This line says "Undeclared identifier "SQL"". Other question: in the if sentence we need a condition, would be "=true", isn't it?

Comment: Code like:

 except
    Result := false;
 end;

*must be always avoided*. Hiding exceptions just make identifying issues much more complex once the code is deployed. Never, never lose any error detail. Always give the user enough error detail so you can understand what went wrong when he or she calls you. If you don't want to display the user full exception information, log them somewhere. Always re-raise any exception you don't handle. Exceptions are a very powerful error handling mechanism, never neuter it because of laziness in writing code.

Comment: @user3780282  SQL is the (dbx) connection component for a datasnap connection, sql is its name in my example.  the if statement "if a then" and "if (a=true) then" then are equivalent in Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calls to remote methods, but they won't automatically update your data aware controls automatically. Datasnap is able to handle it. First, you need to add/update/remove data on the client. It happens in the local cache managed by the TClientDataset, even when you "Post". 
When you're ready, you need to "apply" changes to the remote server calling the Apply() method.
When you call it, the provider component on the server receives a "delta" with the record to change from the client dataset, and will automatically generate the needed INSERT/UPDATED/DELETE SQL statements.
If you don't like them, or you need to perform more complex processing, you can use the provider events to perform the needed operations yourself *for each changed record* and then tell the provider you did it to avoid the automatic processing. Then the provider passes back the "delta" to the client, where it is used to updated the data aware controls. You can also modify the "delta" before it is passed back.
Read in the documentation the explanation of the Datasnap architecture - it's a multistep design where several components work to allow for a multi-tier implementation.

Comment: so the componnent you recommend me is a TClientDataSet on the client side?

Comment: If you want to use the Delphi DB aware components and/or work with a TDataset descendant client side, TClientDataset is the component designed to be the Datasnap client side dataset. It was introduced in Delphi exactly for such task, although it works also alone as a local in-memory dataset. This is the simplest way to write a multi-tier database application in Delphi. Otherwise you can handle everything yourself and just use Datasnap as an RPC mechanism to call remote methods, just you have to write much more code and it becomes far more complex. As I said, the documentation will explain it

Comment: A TClientDataSet should be connected to a DatasetProvider and this to a Tquery or TTAble, but this model is connected directly to the database, isn't it? If this is right, why do you use or develop a "server". i know that ZeosLib for example makes the development easier but this woulbe 2 tiers.

Comment: No, it isn't "connected" directly to the database. The provider and client dataset talk each other over a remoting protocol designed to exchange "table-like" data and their changes. This protocol in turn works over the Datasnap remoting protocol used. The provider acts like a sort of proxy, reading data from a dataset, packaging them into TClientDataset data, and sending them to the client. When "deltas" are sent back by the client dataset, the provider reads the changes, and generates the SQL required to apply them to the database. The client dataset is never connected to the DB directly.

Comment: The reason why you develop a server is exactly to hinder direct connections to the DB. The client does not need the "db client" installed, nor the DB be reachable by it. All accesses to the DB have to go through the server. Here, you can enforce data access rules, which are much harder to bypass since the client can't issue direct SQL commands to the DB. Also, with Datasnap implementaqtions that properly support it, you can protect the communication channel even for databases that don't do it, or require you to buy optional features.